# How to get data that is referenced in different collection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb

I've got 2 collections:

**1.Universities:**

```
[
 {
     "_id": {
      "$oid": "11a34ee333evf38"
     },
     "name": "Stanford University"
 },

 {
     "_id": {
      "$oid": "11e34e8o33evf66"
     },
     "name": "Columbia University"
 }
]
```

**2.Students:**

```
[
 {
     "_id":{
      "$oid":"9858gtht8r4wec3"
     },
     "name": "James Dean",
     "universityId": "11a34ee333evf38"
 },

 {
     "_id":{
      "$oid":"335g6tht8r4wqq3"
     },
     "name": "Bill Doe",
     "universityId": "11a34ee333evf38"
 },

 {
     "_id":{
      "$oid":"1177gtxr8r4cxc3"
     },
     "name": "Alison Mel",
     "universityId": "11e34e8o33evf66"
 }
]
```

My goal is to display such data in a Table so it looks like this:

### Stanford University

*Student Name*

James Dean

Bill Doe

### Columbia University

*Student Name*

Alison Mel

I am using mongodb. How can I form a query to achieve that?

Comment: why first object in `students` is of different structure from the rest?

Comment: what have you attempted?

Comment: Yeah what's with `$oid`? Are those ids stored that way

Comment: sorry about the students structure - i've fixed that. $oid are ids stored in such way. I've already tried to extract data from both collections ending up with each university displaying all students